# Python programming comparing string to list

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

```
def startsWith(string, lst):
    newlst = [word.lower() for word in lst]
    for word in newlst:
        if string.lower() in lst:
            print(word)
```

Can't get this code to work in Python: This is the problem.

Write a function startsWith that takes two arguments, a target string and a list of words.  It then prints each word in the list that starts with the target string.  To receive full credit, the testing should not be case sensitive, it ignores the case of both the target and the word considered.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider adding some more details to this question regarding what exactly isn't working. If possible, please provide the results you are getting and how they differ from the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

First, I think instead of

```
if string.lower() in lst:
```

you mean

```
if string.lower() in word:
```

`in` isn't quite the same as `startswith` but it should get you going forward.

Something like `word.startswith(string.lower())` will work, but try to avoid calling `string.lower()` repeatedly

Comment: Something I think worth pointing out is that OP's code (even with your changes applied) will print out the *lowercase versions* of matching words. The comparison itself should be case-insensitive but I think it's better to print the unmodified versions of matching words.

Comment: @Tagc, yes I agree. As a bonus, it would save making the temporary list